# multi step form arrange display

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I have created a multi-step form to be able to create a smooth and easy onboarding.

I am not able to properly display the button and the input/label.

I am looking to get the label and input align left and the button previous and next displayed on the same line but one of the left and one on the right. Also my I reach the latest form, the 'next' button is no more displayed and I show a submit.

The code works, it's just the display arrangement which not good.

This how it looks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

and I am more looking for something like this:

[image]

Only the back and Next are not properly dispayed on this image, it should be closer to the input.

Otherwise, it's exactly what I am looking
Label then input (always below the label), and then the buttons below the input and label.

Here is the code:

MasterForm:

```
import React from 'react';
import ClassCreationFormStep1 from './ClassCreationFormStep1'
import ClassCreationFormStep2 from './ClassCreationFormStep2'
import ClassCreationFormStep3 from './ClassCreationFormStep3'
import ClassCreationFormStep4 from './ClassCreationFormStep4'
import ClassCreationFormStep5 from './ClassCreationFormStep5'
import ClassCreationFormStep6 from './ClassCreationFormStep6'
import ClassCreationFormStep7 from './ClassCreationFormStep7'
import ClassCreationFormStep8 from './ClassCreationFormStep8'
import ClassCreationFormStep9 from './ClassCreationFormStep9'
import ClassCreationFormStep10 from './ClassCreationFormStep10'
import ClassCreationFormStep11 from './ClassCreationFormStep11'
import ClassCreationFormStep12 from './ClassCreationFormStep12'
import ClassCreationFormStep13 from './ClassCreationFormStep13'


import './CreateClassOnBoardingForm.css';

class CreateClassOnBoardingForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // Set the initial input values
        this.state = {
          currentStep: 1, // Default is Step 1
          classTeacherName: '',
          classProfilePic: '',
          classEmail: '', 
          className: '',
          classAttendeesWillLearn: '',
          classMaxClass: '',
          classWhatToBring: '',
          classWillBe: '',
          classLocation: '',
          classCost: '',
          typeOfClass: '',
          classExtra: '',
          classPics: '',
        }
        // Bind the submission to handleChange() 
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this._next = this._next.bind(this)
        this._prev = this._prev.bind(this)
      }
    
      _next() {
        let currentStep = this.state.currentStep
        // If the current step is 1 or 2, then add one on "next" button click
        currentStep = currentStep >= 12? 13: currentStep + 1
        this.setState({
          currentStep: currentStep
        })
      }
        
      _prev() {
        let currentStep = this.state.currentStep
        // If the current step is 2 or 3, then subtract one on "previous" button click
        currentStep = currentStep <= 1? 1: currentStep - 1
        this.setState({
          currentStep: currentStep
        })
      }
    
      // Use the submitted data to set the state
      handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        })    
      }
      
      // Trigger an alert on form submission
      handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const { classTeacherName, classProfilePic, classEmail, 
          className, classAttendeesWillLearn,classMaxClass, classWhatToBring,
          classWillBe, classLocation, classCost, typeOfClass, classExtra, classPics  } = this.state
        alert(`Your registration detail: \n 
        classTeacherName: ${classTeacherName} \n 
        classProfilePic: ${classProfilePic} \n
        classEmail: ${classEmail} \n
        className: ${className} \n
        classAttendeesWillLearn: ${classAttendeesWillLearn} \n
        classMaxClass: ${classMaxClass} \n 
        classWhatToBring: ${classWhatToBring} \n
        classWillBe: ${classWillBe} \n
        classLocation: ${classLocation} \n
        classCost: ${classCost} \n
        typeOfClass: ${typeOfClass} \n
        classExtra: ${classExtra} \n
        classPics: ${classPics} \n
        `)

        window.open("/successfull", "_self") //to open new page

      }

      get previousButton(){
        let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
        // If the current step is not 1, then render the "previous" button
        if(currentStep !==1){
          return (
            <button 
              className="blue-button" 
              type="button" onClick={this._prev}>
            Previous
            </button>
          )
        }
        // ...else return nothing
        return null;
      }
      
      get nextButton(){
        let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
        if(currentStep <13){
          return (
            <button 
            className="blue-button" 
            type="button" onClick={this._next}>
            Next
            </button>        
          )
        }
        // ...else render nothing
        return null;
      }

      render() {    
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
          <p>Step {this.state.currentStep} </p> 
            
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <ClassCreationFormStep1 
              currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              classTeacherName={this.state.classTeacherName}
            />
            <ClassCreationFormStep2 
              currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              classProfilePic={this.state.classProfilePic}
            />
            ....
            <ClassCreationFormStep13
              currentStep={this.state.currentStep} 
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              classPics={this.state.classPics}
            />      

            {this.previousButton}
            {this.nextButton}
          </form>
          </React.Fragment>
        )
        }
}

export default CreateClassOnBoardingForm;
```

The Css below is used on the master and child

```
.blue-button {
    border-radius: 21px; 
    background-color: #14cff0; 
    border-color: #14cff0;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.label-txt {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.77;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333333;
}

.form-control-village {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 16px; 
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-align: left;
    color: #616161;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff7255;
    border-top: 0px none;
    border-left: 0px none;
    border-right: 0px none;
}
```

and here is the child form:

1st one:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextContents from '../../assets/translations/TextContents'
import './CreateClassOnBoardingForm.css';

class ClassCreationFormStep1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.currentStep !== 1) { // Prop: The current step
        return null
      }
      return(
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="label-txt" htmlFor="classTeacherName">{TextContents.FormClassTeacherName}</label>
          <input
            className="form-control-village"
            id="classTeacherName"
            name="classTeacherName"
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            value={this.props.classTeacherName} // Prop: The email input data
            onChange={this.props.handleChange} // Prop: Puts data into state
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default ClassCreationFormStep1
```

second one:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextContents from '../../assets/translations/TextContents'
import './CreateClassOnBoardingForm.css';

class ClassCreationFormStep2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.currentStep !== 2) { // Prop: The current step
        return null
      }
      return(
          <div className="form-group">
            <label  className="label-txt" htmlFor="classProfilePic">{TextContents.FormClassProfilePic}</label>
            <input
              className="form-control-village"
              id="classProfilePic"
              name="classProfilePic"
              type="file"
              value={this.props.classProfilePic} // Prop: The email input data
              onChange={this.props.handleChange} // Prop: Puts data into state
            />
          </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default ClassCreationFormStep2
```

and the latest one, when submit shows up

```
import React from 'react';
import TextContents from '../../assets/translations/TextContents'

import './CreateClassOnBoardingForm.css';

class ClassCreationFormStep13 extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.currentStep !== 13) { // Prop: The current step
        return null
      }
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="label-txt" htmlFor="classPics">{TextContents.FormClassPics}</label>
            <input
              className="form-control-village"
              id="classPics"
              name="classPics"
              type="file"
              multiple
              value={this.props.classPics} // Prop: The email input data
              onChange={this.props.handleChange} // Prop: Puts data into state
            />
          </div>
          <button 
              className="blue-button" 
              type="submit">
            {TextContents.SubmitBtn}
            </button>
        </React.Fragment>

      )
    }
  }

  export default ClassCreationFormStep13
```

Any idea how to make it nice like the latest image I have posted

=====

I am looking to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: hey Seb, so you want the blue buttons in your first images to be at the bottom left and right of the screen respectively ?

Comment: @RedBaron thanks. I am not looking to necessarly have them at the bottom and on the far right or left. Something in between would be better. I tried to change the value of bottom/left/right but it's not moving at all.

Comment: @RedBaron thanks. So I try to not have the button on the bottom and on each side. I was thinking something closer to the input form. something like 100px below the input and one button on the left side of the input and the other on the right side

Comment: if you are able to show me a design I can write the code for you

Comment: @RedBaron i have added a pic in the description

Comment: but those buttons appear bottom right and left, I thought you didn't want that now?

Comment: @RedBaron added under the =====

Comment: @RedBaron yes but not stucked on the bottom of the page and each far right and left

Comment: ah got you, ok let me see. one sec

Comment: Seb updated my answer, let me know if it helps or what still doesn't work if it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

if you want them positioned to the bottom left and right you need to set a height and `position: relative`

```
<div className="container>
   <button className="backButton>Back</button>
   <button className="nextButton>Next</button>
</div>

.container {
  height: 200px; // example
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.backButton {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.nextButton {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```